# How to compare two lists and return value and index

Tags: c#, linq, list, indexing, compare

How can I compare two string lists and return this same value and index of the first list?

Example:

```
a = List<string> {a,b,c};
b = List<string> {d,a,c};
```

I need return `c` and index `3` , `a` and index `1`

I am only comparing right now:

```
var duplicateProduct =   productIdList.Where(b => allProduct.Any(a => b.Contains(a)));
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 List<string> listA = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c" };
 List<string> listB = new List<string>() { "d", "a", "c" };

 var result = listA.Select((x, y) => new { element = x, index = y })
    .Where(z => listB.Contains(z.element));
```

EDIT: if you don't want a 0 based index, you can do this instead:

```
var result = listA.Select((x, y) => new { element = x, index = y += 1 })
   .Where(z => listB.Contains(z.element));
```

EDIT2: get duplicates from both lists

```
var list1_duplicates = listA.Select((x, y) => new { element = x, index = y })
           .Where(z => listB.Contains(z.element));

var list2_duplicates = listB.Select((x, y) => new { element = x, index = y })
           .Where(z => listA.Contains(z.element));

var all_duplicates = list1_duplicates.Concat(list2_duplicates);
```

EDIT3: yet another update of the code where we retrieve the indexes on both lists for each element, also managing duplicates in the same list

```
List<string> listA = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c" };
List<string> listB = new List<string>() { "d", "a", "c", "a" };

var result = listA.Select((a) => new
{
    element = a,
    indexA = listA.IndexOf(a),
    indexB = Enumerable.Range(0, listB.Count).Where(b => listB[b].Equals(a)).ToArray()
});
```

(optional) Add

```
    .Where(a => listB.Contains(a.element));
```

before the ";" to retrieve only elements present in the second list

Comment: I have one more question. if i need the second index too what i need to do ?

Comment: @Aranfea you mean the duplicates from the second list? I have updated my answer

Comment: I want to show this same data + index of second list eg.   listA  { "a", "b", "c" };
listB  { "d", "a", "c" }; I want show : "a" , "1" - index of listA , "2" - index of listB

Comment: @Aranfea but what if an element is repeated more than once inside the same list, say listA { "a", "b", "c" }; listB { "d", "a", "c", "a" }; what should the output be for a? {"a", "1", "{2, 4}"}? or should I discard this possibility?

Comment: it would be perfect solution

Answer (score 1):

```
var duplicateProduct =   productIdList.Where(b => allProduct.Any(a => b.Contains(a)))
                         .Select(x => new { x, index = productIdList.IndexOf(x)});
```

This will create an IEnumerable of anonymous types of the item and the index of that item in the `productIdList` list.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it might help you.

```
var al =new  List<string> { "a","b","c"};
var bl = new List<string> { "d","a","c"};

var res = (from a in al
           join b in bl
           on a equals b
           select new
           {
               Matched = a,
               Index = al.IndexOf(a)
           }).ToList();
```